# Custom init with id to ViewController in Objective-C from Swift code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need help you with convert my Swift code to Objective-c.

There is my Swift code.

```
 self.show(ChatViewController(conversation: conversation!), sender: self)
```

I have no idea how to convert them to with init "conversation". This is Id of conversation for my chat in Socket.

```
 ChatViewController *chatVC = [[ChatViewController alloc] init];
            [vc showViewController: chatVC sender:self];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what `conversation` type is, but swift constructor

`ChatViewController(conversation: conversation!)`

in Objective-C is

```
ChatViewController *chatVC = [[ChatViewController alloc] 
    initWithConversation:conversation];
```

Answer (score 1):

All Swift stuff must be marked `@objc public` to be visible in Objective-C. In this case that would be the `ChatViewController` class, its `init(conversation:)`, and whatever the conversation type is.

If you do that correctly, Objective-C should be able to import your generated interface header (find this in your build settings, it usually looks like "AppName-Swift.h").

Then the Swift methods would be automatically converted to Objective-C style methods so you would be able to call

```
ChatViewController *chatVC = [[ChatViewController alloc] initWithConversation:converstaion];
```

Answer (score 0):

May be Swift can't bridge your `conversation` object